# Does strstr() have a size limit in C?

Tags: c

I am using `strstr()` to compare an XML response versus an expected response.  On shorter tests, this has worked properly, but now on the larger strings I am seeing two buffers exactly equal one another, but `strstr()` is failing to catch it.

The XML string response I am failing on is 502 bytes in size, so I'm expecting `strstr()` to find an occurrence of a 502 byte string inside a 502 byte string.

Example:

```
if( strstr(msgPointer, xmlcheckstring) )
{
    printf("Good response!\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Bad response :(\n");
}
```

Where `msgPointer` points to my receive buffer and `xmlcheckstring` contains a constant string to check against.  And again, this worked for smaller tests (~200 bytes in size).

I'm just curious if anyone has had any experience with this.  Thanks,

Comment: If you are comparing a known response to an incoming one, wouldn't strcmp() be a better choice? http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp

Comment: `strstr()` should be able to handle any string which is not longer than `2 ^ (sizeof(size_t) * 8` - this really should be at least 65535 on most modern systems. You're missing something else.

Comment: Are you certain they're equal to each other?  Does `memcmp(msgPointer, xmlCheckstring, length) == 0`?

Comment: Can you post the code that populates `msgPointer` (or the buffer to which it points)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments... Let me test some of these responses to see if I'm just being a bozo.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, no memcmp = 10 in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/) can be a useful source if you want to check the implementation of standard C functions.

Their version of [strstr](http://svn.freebsd.org/base/user/eri/pf45/head/lib/libc/string/strstr.c) will look very similar to other standard library implementations and confirms there are no limitations that'd affect the relatively small strings you're dealing with.

Comment: Thanks to all the responses:  you've shown me some new tools.  I found the issue:  a rogue '\n' was picked up in my xmlCheckstring.  *forehead slap*.  Thank you for answering my question on strstr() limitations however, as I could not find this answer online.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a limit, it's unlikely to be much below MAXINT

I'm going to have a guess that you're searching for a string in data that you've read from a TCP stream socket? If so, be aware that `read()` can return less bytes than you've requested and you may need to call `read()` multiple times to get the entire XML message that you're looking for...